# Firefox on Red hat 5.6

Tags: firefox, redhat

What is the maximum version of Firefox that can run on Red hat 5.6?

The default installation is 3.2.6... I want to run some WebDriver tests but having issues which are due to the Firefox version.

When attempting to update Firefox to 35.0 a error arises with libgio-2.0.so.0()(64bit) not found.

I believe this library is in GLib package and internal to the OS so can't be updated?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox puts out what they call ESRs (Extended Service Releases) which typically have a wider target audience of distributions that they support. **ESR 17 was the last to work on CentOS 5.x** so I wouldn't expect to go much further than this one.

What is Mozilla Firefox ESR?

Mozilla will offer an Extended Support Release (ESR) based on an official release of Firefox for desktop for use by organizations including schools, universities, businesses and others who need extended support for mass deployments. You can read more about the plan here.
Version 24 of Firefox will become ESR 24, and this version definitely will not run on CentOS 5.x (according to the testing I've done on 5.9). So you're essentially stuck on this older version until Mozilla releases a newer version built with the older libraries support.